# How can I loop through files and identify files by string in filename

Tags: python

In Python: I'm trying to loop through files in a directory, find the files that have a certain string in their file name, open and edit those files.  It all seems to be working except being able to select specific files in the directory based on the string:

```
import re
import datetime as dt
OldValue = input('Enter the value to be replaced: ')
NewValue = input('Enter the replacement value: ')
location = input('Enter path to directory: ')
directory = os.listdir(location)
os.chdir(location)
for root, dirs,files in os.walk('.'):
    for fname in files:
        re.match('PMPM', fname)

for f in os.listdir(location):
    for file in directory:
                open_file = open(file, 'r')
                read_file = open_file.read()
                regex = re.compile(OldValue)
                read_file = regex.sub(NewValue, read_file)
                write_file = open(file, 'w')
                write_file.write(read_file)
                now = dt.datetime.now()
                ago = now-dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
for root, dirs,files in os.walk('.'):
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
st = os.stat(path)
mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
if mtime > ago:
    print('%s modified %s' % (path,  mtime))
```

Comment: There is a `for f in ...` and a `for file in ...` which are both iterating over `os.listdir(location)`, however, only `file` is used. It looks like one of the loops is unnecessary.

Comment: I think I understood the question now. Do you want to select the files whose name start with `'PMPM'`? Thats why the `re.match` is there. It was puzzling me because you do a match but then you don't store the result nor use it. In addition, the list of files from `os.walk()` contains files in subdirectories of your actual dir.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is a list of the filenames from a given directory containing a given substring then something like this should work:

```
#!python
import os
dir='.'         # Replace with path to your directory: absolute or relative
pattern = 'foo' # Replace with your target substring
matching_files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir) if pattern in f]
```

That's all you need for the simplest case.  You can then iterate over the list of *matching_files*

If you want to walk down a directory tree with [os.walk()](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/) then you have to search the third item from each tuple returned by the generator.

*os.walk()* recurses down a tree returning a tuple for each subdirectory. Each of these consists of three items: the leading path, the list of subdirectories below that, and the list of filenames (directory entries for anything OTHER than a subdirectory) at that node.

However, there's also a trick!  You'll need to prefix each match with that dirpath item at that level.  In other words for every match in tuple(os.walk(...))[2] (the list) you need to yield the concatenation of that with the corresponding string from tuple(os.walk(...))[0] to get a full (absolute or relative) path to the matching filename.

One way to get a feel for how this works is to load up your Python interpreter (preferably iPython from the Jupyter project), instantiate a generator with *walker = os.walk(dir)* (where *dir* is any valid directory to use as the starting point) and then call *this = next(walker)* and you can look at *this[0]* and *this[2]* before going on to look at the *next(walker)*.

Let's start with code which returns a list using simple substring matching (as I did with my previous example, but over multiple lines for clarity):

```
#!python
results = list()
dir = '.'
walker = os.walk(dir)
delimiter = os.path.sep
pattern = '.txt'
for p,_,f in walker:
  matches = ['%s%s%s' % (p, delimiter, x) for x in f if pattern in f]
  results.extend(matches)
```

In this case I'm using the tuple unpacking of the *for* loop to give me the path and file list components from each tuple yielded by the *os.walk()* generator.  The matches, at each node in the tree, are extracted in a list comprehension which is also prefixing each match with the path (and using the *os.path.sep* to make the code portable across different operating system platforms).

Also notice that _ is just a variable name in Python, but it's conventionally used to "throw away" some value.  In other words using _ as a variable in Python is a hint to readers and maintainers that this was some unwanted stuff that your code is not interested in using later.

It would be better to write this as a generator function and yield results rather than perform the full traversal (potentially consuming time and memory).  With our own generator wrapped around *os.walk()* we could more easily process each match subject to other conditions (find the first, the first N, wrap in even more filtering, and so on).

Also I'm using simple substring matching (using Python's *in* operator, which calls the *[._ _contains_ _()](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/contains-method.html)* special method.  We can use regular expressions for this ... though I commend being wary of *re.match()* which only matches patterns at the beginning of each string against which it's matched.

So here's that:

```
#!python
import os, re
def matchwalk(regex, directory):
    '''Yield path/filenames matching some regular expression
    '''
    sep = os.path.sep
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    for p,_,f in os.walk(directory):
        for each in f:
            if pattern.search(each):
                yield '{0}{1}{2}'.format(p,sep,each)
```

This is similar to the previous code example.  The differences: I've wrapped it in a function, I'm using *yield* so the function is a generator (just like *os.walk()*).  I'm using regular expressions; I prefer to use *re.compile()* for legibility (there might be some marginal performance benefit as well, but probably not under most Python implementations as the *re* module will often do it's on interning of regular expression just as Python does interning of many strings).  Also I'm using the newer style string formatting function (though I personally prefer the old syntax; this is just for edification).

Comment: Appreciate everyone’s help.  I’m up and running!

Comment: @JimHerbert: You might want to upvote those answers which were helpful and select whichever answer you feel would be best for those who search on this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the standard [**unix style pathname pattern expansoin**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) package, or simply `glob`.

---

Running through all files with a filename starting with, say `'PMPM'`, in a specific directory, say `'~/path/to/mydir'`, is a simple as:

```
import os
import glob

pattern = os.path.join(
    os.path.expanduser('~'),
    'path/to/mydir',
    'PMPM*' # mind the * here!
)

for matching_file in glob.glob(pattern):
    with open(matching_file, 'r') as f:
        # do something with the file object
        pass
```

Or the same in short:

```
from glob import glob
for mf in glob('home/someuser/path/to/mydir/PMPM*'):
    with open(mf, 'r') as f:
        pass # do something with f
```

Comment: Thank you jojo.  This gets me almost there but I'm getting an error on line 15: "write_file = open(read_file, 'w')"

Comment: **1.** Do not use `file` as a custom variable, name it differently, like `my_file` or something. `file` is a built in constructor you should not overwite. _this is not the problem though_.
**2.** The problem lies in line 11 where you open the file for reading, but you never close it! you need to close a file object! You can call `open_file.close()` once you're done reading it or even better use the `with` statement as I do above. It will pay of to read through the [docs about Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Thanks @jojo - yes I did.  Appreciate the help.